# How to restart ALSA without restarting the raspberry pi itself?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa

I have a Rasperry Pi 3 with an external USB Sound Card. Everything is working fine... sometimes. Some other times the Raspberry Pi is starting up and there is some problem with the sounds system. Sound is not working. When I try to open alsamixer it is saying like "Error while opening the mixer device: No device found" (it's in german... this is the rough translation).
If I get this error, then I have to restart the whole raspberry pi. It would be much nicer if I could just restart alsa somehow. But till now I could not find out how.
OS is Raspbian

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```sh
sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils stop
sudo alsa force-reload
sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils start
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But "sudo alsa force-reload" gives an error. "Sudo: alsa: Command not found" (sudo: alsa: Befehl nicht gefunden).

Comment: which version of raspian do you use

Comment: Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Kernel: Linux 4.9.59-v7+

Comment: Right now I don't have a raspberry at hand, have you tried to run `sudo alsactl kill rescan`

Comment: Sorry, seems this doesn't work in Raspberry OS (Debian 11).